# In Meteor, how do you detect when a new user has logged in?

Tags: meteor

The documentation:

http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_userId

says

> This is constant. However, if the logged-in user changes, the publish
>   function is rerun with the new value.

Is there some way of running some event driven code which fires only on the event that the logged in user changes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Meteor.user()`, `Meteor.userId()` and `Meteor.userLoaded()` are all reactive datasources ([documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user)).

If you place them inside a template helper or build your own context around them, you'll notice when the current user changes.

Comment: In many cases, [`Meteor.autorun`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_autorun) can be used, outside the context of a template helper.

Comment: Has `Meteor.autorun` always been in there? Never seen this before/read over it. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: `Meteor.autorun` is now `Deps.autorun`

Comment: `Deps.autorun` is now `Tracker.autorun`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it via Subscription and you can track the user and log inside the server.
See [my blog](http://meteorhacks.com/logging-support-for-meteor.html)

Navigate to the code section in the blog post.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

`{{#if currentUser}}` might work for you in your template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `currentUser` helper.

Here is an example of how it would work:

```
  {{#if currentUser}}
     <p>User logged code</p>
  {{else}}
     <p>User not logged code</p> 
  {{/if}}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.